# What happens if the client acts wrong connecting to Netty server?

Tags: netty

So say I have the following decoder...

```
public class MyDecoder extends FrameDecoder1 {

    @Override
    protected Object decode(
            ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Channel channel, ChannelBuffer buffer)2 {

        if (buffer.readableBytes() < 4) {
            return null;
        }

        return buffer.readBytes(4);
    }
}
```

What happens if a client connects and never sends 4 bytes?

1- Client connects sends 3 bytes closes connection. Netty discards everything related to that connection right all resources "freed"?

2- Client connects sends 3 bytes does not close connection and keeps it open. Another client connects and does the same thing and it continues. At this point resources are taken right? Is there a default way to handle this or do I need to attach a read timeout handler or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes as soon as the channel is closed it will release the buffered bytes.
2) Have a look at IdleStateHandler and IdleStateAwareHandler. These will help you to disconnect the client after some inactivity.